# Ввод двумерного массива с консоли

Tags: java

Моя задача: считать с консоли двумерный `byte` массив. Чтобы он записался в переменную и в дальнейшем я с ним работал. Представляю себе это примерно так: пользователь вводит первую строку, жмет Enter, вторую, пишет `go` и алгоритм обработки массива запускается. Вот что я пробую:

```
 public static byte[][] input(int strok, int stolb){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    byte X[][]=new byte[strok][stolb];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<strok; i++){
        for (j=0; j<stolb; j++){
            X[i][j]=sc.nextByte();
        }
    }
    return X;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите количество строк: ");
    int strok=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите количество столбцов: ");
    int stolb=sc.nextInt();
    Table pokr1=new Table(input(strok,stolb));
    pokr1.putArr();
```

Comment: в чём вопрос то?

Comment: как это реализовать? как обработать этот энтер, чтобы он означал переход на следующую строку? этот код вообще вызывает ошибку Value out of range, когда я что либо пытаюсь ввести

Comment: а как вызов метода происходит? что в `main`? напишите код мейна

Comment: Ухх.. а что за Table?

Comment: это класс, который содержит в себе алгоритмы по преобразованию этого массива. Я не могу понять, как реализовать ввод массива, в остальном проблем нет

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема вся в том, что `byte` такой тип, у которого диапазонами возможных значений от -128 до 127. Как следствие, если ввести число меньше, чем -127 или больше 128, то получим ошибку `Value out of range`

Скорее всего при вводе чисел вы как раз и указываете недопустимое значение.

Можно в таком случае либо изменить тип данных на бОльший, к примеру `int` и работать с ним.

Либо контролировать, что ввел пользователь, отлавливая ошибку и сообщать пользователю, что он должен ввести числа в таком-то диапазоне.

Comment: Все, вопрос закрыт, спасибо